# Teamcity: How run only pull request commits

Tags: github, teamcity

I setup a build (on TeamCity 8.1) to pull request on github, but it always performs all the commits.

How do I run only pull request commits (just one user)?

Current configuration: `+:refs/pull/(*)/merge`

Answer (score 1):

When you create a pull request, GitHub basically creates two new branches, one for the pull, and one for the pull + merge. You are specifying the "merge" branch to build which will trigger a new build for ANY action that GitHub thinks might alter the merge. Even just opening the PR to look at can activate the VCS trigger in TeamCity.

If you want to ONLY build from the PR itself, change the "merge" to "head" like this:

```
+:refs/(pull/*)/head
```